# Reasonable choice of MachinePrecision, AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal for NDSolve

Tags: machine-precision

I am trying to use this model for later use in FindFit:

```
model[x0_?NumberQ, r_?NumberQ, k_?NumberQ, n_?NumberQ] := model[x0, r, k, n] = 
   First[x /. NDSolve[{x'[t] == r x[t] (1 - x[t]/k)^n, x[0] == x0}, x, {t, 0, 61}]]
```

Assume now that those parameters are sought within the following ranges:

```
x0: 10^-50..10^-10;
n: 0.1..5.0;
r: 1..10;
k: 1..1000.
```

Depending on the specific choice of the parameter combination I will get various NDSolve numeric errors. So what would be a good choice of MachinePrecision, AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal that would work for that parameter space?

Comment: I have an idea what the issue is, but I wanted to be sure I understand what you're asking.  I've tried several inputs and can get no error **messages** (V10.0.1, Mac OSX).  Or do you mean only that the computed result looks wrong?

Comment: It varies. Can be NDSolve error messages such as NDSolve::precw: The precision of the differential equation (...) is less than WorkingPrecision (40.), or indeed simply the InterpolatingFunction returned (without NDSolve errors) is just nonsensical.

Comment: I won't have time to write up an answer for a few days, but here are couple things to consider. For `n >= 1`, the options `PrecisionGoal -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, WorkingPrecision -> 100` seem to take care of everything I tried.  A `WorkingPrecision` around `100` seems to be needed for `x0` as small as `10^-50` -- the smaller `x0`, the greater the precision needed.  Second, I think for `n < 1`, `x` reaches `k` in finite time.  I haven't figured out a graceful way to stop the integration at the right time.  Also `n = 1.01` behaves like `n < 1` -- not sure why exactly.

Comment: The message `NDSolve::precw` can be ignored.  Ideally you would pass parameters `x0`, `r`, `k`, and `n` with a precision at least as great as the `WorkingPrecision` -- then you should not get the message.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a variant of the logistic growth population model, so I'll call x "population size".  A few thoughts:

First, in such cases I've had good luck with `AccuracyGoal->Infinity` when dealing with low population sizes.  This is because a small absolute error in population size will be critical when you're around the unstable equilibrium x=0.  This seemed to fix any problem I had with your model (as long as n wasn't too small).

Second, it might also help to deal with log population sizes, since exponential population growth is linear on a log scale.  That is,

```
model2[x0_?NumberQ, r_?NumberQ, k_?NumberQ, n_?NumberQ] := model2[x0, r, k, n] =
First[lnx /. NDSolve[{lnx'[t] == r  (1 - E^lnx[t]/k)^n, lnx[0] == Log[x0]}, lnx, {t, 0, 61}]]
```

Third, it seems like this particular model has an analytical solution available through `DSolve`:

```
DSolve[{x'[t] == r x[t] (1 - x[t]/k)^n, x[0] == x0}, x, t]
```

gives

```
{{x -> Function[{t}, InverseFunction[
-((Hypergeometric2F1[n,n,1+n,k/#1](1-k/#1)^n (1-#1/k)^-n)/n)&][rt-((1-k/x0)^n (1-x0/k)^-n Hypergeometric2F1[n,n,1+n,k/x0])/n]
]}}
```

Comment: Indeed, would you know how I could use that solution for fitting instead?

Comment: Sorry I don't have much experience with fitting models.  Maybe someone else could chime in?